# Could not load file or assembly log4net, Version 1.2.10.0 - Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

> "Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference"

I have a VB application which compiles to an EXE.  The EXE worked fine on the old 32 bit Windows Server 2003 machine, but when I try to run it on the new 64 bit Server 2008 R2 machine I get the above error.

I have spent hours and hours reading similar threads on this site and others, as well as trying different dlls in the runtime directory of the EXE with no success.  When I remove the dll from the folder, the error message changes to indicate that it can't find ANY log4net dll, so I know it's looking in that folder for the appropriate dll.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the appropriate runtime and all is well.  I think I had installed the 32bit runtime, which didn't work out well.